# How to use Azure Key Vault & Azure Active Directory B2C in different directories?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-keyvault

I am attempting to follow [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-get-started#register) to set up Azure Key Vault, and I am on the step to "Register an application with Azure Active Directory".

In the instructions, there is this guideline:

> Important: To complete the tutorial, your account, the vault, and the application that you will register in this step must all be in the same Azure directory.

Three important pieces of info about my configuration:

1. Since our team is using Azure Active Directory B2C and not Azure AD, the AAD B2C instance is in a different directory, as shown in the top right corner of the screenshot below.
2. Our web app (name `MyApp`) is registered to AAD B2C within `Directory2`, as shown by the circle in the middle of the screenshot below.
   [image]
3. However, the actual Web Application resource is in `Directory1`, as shown in the screenshot below
   [image]

**How should I move forward? Should I move the KeyVault & MyApp to Directory2 or move the AAD B2C instance to Directory1?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, You cannot use Azure KeyVault for Azure AD B2C Application.

**Why?**

1.For your sceanrio,generally,we can secure Azure Web App with Azure AD and Azure AD B2C. However, for Azure AD B2C application, the key can only be generated by Azure. You cannot  use a custom key for AAD Application.

2.AAD B2C application is not with a service principal. If you want to authorize the application to use the key or secret, you may use following powershell scripts:

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName 'ContosoKeyVault' -ServicePrincipalName 8f8c4bbd-485b-45fd-98f7-ec6300b7b4ed -PermissionsToKeys decrypt,sign
```

However,this powershell cmdelet needs to speicfy one `Serviceprincipal Name`. AAD B2C is not with a service principal. So,you cannot use this powershell for AAD B2C App.

So,even you can let the key vault and AAD B2C application are in a same tenant, but you still cannot use the key vault for AAD B2C.

**My Suggestions:**

Although you can integrate AAD B2C to do authentication/authorization for your Azure Web App, but this feature is designed for AAD,NOT Azure AD B2C. However,you can still integrate AAD B2C with your web App, but you cannot use keyvault for your B2C app. I'm sorry for this suitation, but B2C is for develop environment,it's not likes AAD.

If you mind use generated key by Azure and need this feature, you can post your idea in [**this Feedback Forum**](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160596-b2c), Azure Team will review it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you please elaborate on "For your scenario, generally, we can secure Azure Web App with Azure AD and Azure AD B2C"? If I associate the Azure Web App object with Azure AD can I then use KeyVault? If this is not possible, is there another password-keeper like KeyVault that can be used instead in this scenario?

Comment: Hi,@Emilia . You got it. If you use AAD to authenticate Azure Web App, you can use KeyVault. As I known, AAD B2C doesn't support other paasword-keeper , even Azure keyVault. You known, it can only use the key which generated with itself.